# 'trueText' property for boolean row in propertygrid (for Yes|No style)

Tags: javascript, extjs, propertygrid

I looking for `trueText` property for boolean row in propertygrid (like Ext.`grid.column.BooleanView` 'trueText'). Any suggestion's?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) for that.

```
renderer: function(value){
    // evaluates `value` to append either `person' or `people`
    return Ext.util.Format.plural(value, 'person', 'people');
}
```